# Sort data based on the difference of two columns

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

```
ID    Vote_Up    Vote_Down    ***DIFFERENCE***
1         3            1             2
2         1            3            -2
3         23           7             16
4         5            1             4
5         7            5             2
6         2            2             0
7         9            1             8
```

How do i sort the data above in mysql based on the difference of Vote_Up and Vote_Down Without having to create another column to store their difference?

```
vote_up - vote_down
```

So that it will be sorted this way:

```
ID    Vote_Up    Vote_Down    ***DIFFERENCE***
3         23           7             16
7         9            1             8    
4         5            1             4
5         7            5             2
1         3            1             2
6         2            2             0
2         1            3            -2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Konerak:
DIFFERENCE is not a field.
Use this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Vote_Up - Vote_Down DESC;
```

or

```
SELECT *, Vote_Up - Vote_Down as DIFFERENCE FROM table ORDER BY DIFFERENCE DESC;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for your comment, but **you can't signal another user by mentioning his @name in your answer** - only in comments on his questions/answers/comments. You can post your answer here, and usually leave a comment on my question 'Difference is not a field, look at my answer for another solution'. Offcourse, first you do need 50 reputation to comment everywhere...

Comment: No problem. The first days are not really a good representation of the actual StackOverflow system, since you're still very restricted because of reputation. Once you have a 100, a world opens, then at 3k you're home free :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just substract them:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Vote_Up-Vote_Down DESC
```

Comment: **Without having to create another column to store their difference

Comment: Correct. The data is calculated for each row. You can offcourse select the data as a column itself too: `SELECT *, Vote_Up - Vote_Down AS DIFFERENCE FROM table  ORDER BY Vote_Up-Vote_Down DESC`.

Answer (score 1):

One more variant (with a subquery) -

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ID, Vote_Up, Vote_Down, Vote_Up - Vote_Down DIFFERENCE FROM table_name
) t
ORDER BY DIFFERENCE;
```